# Problema com INSERT utilizando " aspas "

Tags: php, sql

no meu script esta funcionando, quando posto um texto normal insere normal, porem quando tento postar algum codigo tipo   sou redirecionado para a pagina de erro 403

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access envia.php on this server.Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.Protected by COMODO WAF Server at Port 80

Estou utilizando ckeditor no textarea e meu codigo que envia esta o seguinte esta o seguinte:

```
if ($acao == "adicionar" ) {
$titulo = trim($_POST['titulo']);
$categoria = trim($_POST['categoria']);
$data = trim($_POST['data']);
$autor = trim($_POST['autor']);
$status = trim($_POST['status']);
$destacar = trim($_POST['destacar']);
$conteudo = trim($_POST['conteudo']);
$error = FALSE;

if (!$error) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO `noticias` (`titulo`, `categoria`, `data`, `conteudo`, `status`, `destacar`, `autor`) VALUES "
        . "( :titulo, :categoria, :data, :conteudo, :status, :destacar, :autor)";

try {
  $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

  // bind the values
  $stmt->bindValue(":titulo", $titulo);
  $stmt->bindValue(":conteudo", $conteudo);
  $stmt->bindValue(":status", $status);
  $stmt->bindValue(":destacar", $destacar);
  $stmt->bindValue(":autor", $autor);

  // execute Query
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->rowCount();
  if ($result > 0) {
    $_SESSION["errorType"] = "success";
    $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Adicionado com Sucesso.";
  } else {
    $_SESSION["errorType"] = "danger";
    $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Falha ao adicionar.";
  }
} catch (Exception $ex) {

  $_SESSION["errorType"] = "danger";
  $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = $ex->getMessage();
}
}
```

Comment: Você esta sem permissão para acessar o arquivo `envia.php`.

Comment: mais esta a permissao 755 estou pesquisando sobre, estou achando que e algo no ckeditor que esta fazendo isso, pois tenho outro campo onde aceita aspas, tentei agora dar permissao 777 e mesmo assim nao insere